# Charset UTF-8 only working on some pages

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

I have defined my charset with `<meta charset="UTF-8">` between my html head tags.

On the `index.html` my copyright symbol (the only symbol I have on my pages) is working fine, but for some reason when I check my `register.html` page, it appears as a question mark.

I have literally copied my entire `index.html` code, where the symbol is working fine, to my `register.html` code, but it still appears as a question mark. So I'm thinking it has to do with the file names.

Does anybody know what could be the problem here? Because I'm kinda lost.

I am running on a local host (xampp) if that helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

check the files encoding, both files are written in utf-8? You can download for example notepad++ and in "format" menu you will see what kind of file encoding is.

Answer (score 0):

How did you place the copyright symbol? 
In text: [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [C] ? = © 
HTML Tag: `&copy;` = © 
Or by number: `&#169;` = © 
It might be that your HTML is bugging the symbol, because it does not understand it.

Comment: I placed the symbol in text: ©

Comment: Try to use the &copy; HTML tag or the number (&#169;). It might solve your problem.